# Как посмотреть содержимое подключаемого файла?

Tags: android, c++

В андроид студии в c++ подключаются файл из библиотеки 'GLES2/gl2.h', как его открыть для чтения?

Comment: редактором пробовали?

Comment: Да-да, надо редактором, но как его открыть ? Где этот файл находится ?

Comment: Все зависит от того, какая у Вас операционная система. В линуксе этот файл обычно здесь "/usr/include/GLES2/gl2.h"

Comment: О, у меня mac os x

Comment: Здесь мне сложно что то сказать точно, но скорее всего `find / -name "gl2.h" в консоле все найден (хотя, сканить весь диск может быть не так и быстро.

Comment: спасибо! нашёл и открыл)